# An exercise in asymptotic analysis : under some hypothesis show that $f(x+g(x))\sim f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

This is the first part of an exercise from Infitesimal Calculus by Jean Dieudonné.
Let $f$, $g$ be two continuously differentiable and strictly positive functions near $+\infty$.
First question: suppose $f'$ is monotonic and $\neq0$ near $+\infty$. Show that if $g=o(f/f')$ then $f(x+g(x))\sim f(x)$ as $x\to+\infty$ (use the mean value theorem). Show that this isn't true if we only suppose $g=O(f/f')$.

What I tried : Let $x$ be near infinity. Using the mean value theorem there exist a unique  $t\in(x,x+g(x))$ such that $f(x+g(x))-f(x)=f'(t)g(x)$. If $f'$ is bounded then it follows from $g=o(f/f')$ that $g=o(f)$ so $\frac{f'(t)g(x)}{f(x)}$ tends to $0$.
But if $f'$ is not bounded near infinity I fail to make progress in showing that $\frac{f'(t)g(x)}{f(x)}$ tends toward $0$.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: By writing the definition with epsilons i figured i could majorize $1/f'$ but i cannot if $f'$ tends towards zero so it is false but this was the reason.

Comment: Can you see that $\frac{{f'(t)g(x)}}{{f(x)}} = \frac{{f'(x)g(x)}}{{f(x)}}\frac{{f'(t)}}{{f'(x)}} = o(1)\frac{{f'(t)}}{{f'(x)}}$?

Comment: Yes i do. But after that I do not know how to compare the growths of $f'(t)$ and $f'(x)$. I tried using the fact that $f'$ is monotonic to write inequalities like $f'(x)\le f'(t)\le f'(x+g(x))$ and start from there but it seems to lead me nowhere.